# Where am I making mistake in creating this function to search element from singly linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I'm trying to make a function which searches element from singly linked list and returns address of the value found. otherwise returns null.
But when I enter the value to search only the value at 1st node/position  gets searched. For all the other input value it returns NULL and the message pops up saying "Item not found"
Means it only works for the head node but I can't understand why. I thought the while loop would traverse till the end and if the element matched the data in the list it would return the address which is not happening at all.

HERE'S MY CODE:

```
node *searchData(int key)
{
node *curNode=head; //head is global variable

 while (curNode!=NULL)
 {

  if(curNode->data==key)
     { 

       return curNode;
       break;

     }
else
return NULL;
curNode=curNode->link;
    }
}
```

MY MAIN FUNCTION:

```
 cout<<"Enter The element to search?"<<endl;
        cin>>elem;
         b=searchData(elem);//use searchData function here

         if(b==NULL)
            cout<<"Item Not Found!!";
         else
                cout<<"Element "<<elem<<" was found at address:    "<<b<<endl;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
node *searchData(int key)
{
  node *curNode=head; //head is global variable

   while (curNode!=NULL)
   {

     if(curNode->data==key)
     { 
       return curNode;
       // break; // redundant, you have already returned.

     }
     // else // no need to guard code against True, True returned.

     // return NULL; // your not done going thru the linked list yet
     curNode=curNode->link;
   }
   return NULL; // went thru the list to no avail.
}
```

the short version

```
node *searchData(int key)
{
  for( node *curNode=head; curNode!=NULL; curNode=curNode->link)
    if(curNode->data==key)
      return curNode;

  return NULL;
}
```